# Why a react app won't be too big with too many components? How do people mitigate this risk?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, frontend

As a beginner, I found out all my components will be built into one bundle and be loaded in one html. Even I have many pages, each using different dependencies, that will at the end be combined into one large js.

But in normal server-side render app, each page can have its own component and its own dependencies.

Will a react app be too big when there is many components?
How do people deal with it in the industry?

Answer (score 2):

Code splitting & lazy loading is what you need to research for solving this issue. You may also search for `Suspense` while you are at it.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way these days is to use a technique called **Lazy Loading**. It consists of only loading the main page of the app initially, and other pages load only when requested.

Check out this article from the official docs https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

The side effect is that rather having a single JS file upon building the app, we'll have many; one file per page.